# MultipartFile upload from Feign Client giving 403 Forbidden error

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc, spring-boot, feign

i am trying to call the api through feign client and upload the file along with some string parameter through MultipartFile.

This is my client code:

```
package com.abc;

import feign.codec.Encoder;

@FeignClient(url = "https://xys.com", name = "uploadfile", configuration = UploadFileFeign.MultipartSupportConfig.class)
public interface UploadFileFeign {

    @PostMapping(value = "leaveApplication", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ObjectRestResponse<?> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(value = "request") String request,
            @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile srcFile);


    class MultipartSupportConfig {
        @Bean
        public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
            return new FeignSpringFormEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        public feign.Logger.Level multipartLoggerLevel() {
            return feign.Logger.Level.FULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the API code which my client is calling.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/services/leaveApplication", method=Request.POST, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, headers="Accept=application/json")
public ResponseOutput leaveApplication(@RequestParam("request") String request, @RequestParam(value = "file", required=false) MultipartFile srcFile) throws Exception {
}
```

But i am getting error in response:
403 - Forbidden error.
You do not have permission to access the /services/leaveApplication

Other api's which do not involve file upload are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typo here :

Request mapping URL is  : `/services/leaveApplication`

But you are accessing :  `/service/leaveApplication`

**Change `service` to `services`**

Comment: Hi, sorry the url i typed was not correct. Its corrected now. Its not a url issue as app urls are in sync

Comment: always copy and paste the error logs and code instead of typing manually.

Comment: Yes, but logs are on client machine. i cant copy them